# SimpleSAMLPHP NoState error

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

i have two simplesamlphp servers set up, they are both on the same physical server but separated by virtualhost. they are currently at the domains.

`id.saml.domain.com` <- Identity provider

`sp.saml.domain.com` <- Service provider

I also have a third site, the webs application that i actually intend to implement single sign on at. we'll call that

`test.domain.com/webapplication`

i have the service provider and the identity provider talking to each other using example-auth. i can go to the service provider, click 'test authentication sources', get sent to the identity server, and then get a login prompt, enter the example credentials, click submit, and get sent back to the service provider.

at this point, everything looks good.

my problem is, when i try to implement the service provider in the website.

i have the following login code in place to call the service provider code

```
    $lib = "/ltsites/saml/service/lib";
    $sp = "default-sp";  // Name of SP defined in config/authsources.php

    try {
        // Autoload simplesamlphp classes.
        if(!file_exists("{$lib}/_autoload.php")) {
            throw(new Exception("simpleSAMLphp lib loader file does not exist: ".
            "{$lib}/_autoload.php"));
        }

        include_once("{$lib}/_autoload.php");
        $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($sp);

        // Take the user to IdP and authenticate.
        $as->requireAuth();
        $valid_saml_session = $as->isAuthenticated();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // SimpleSAMLphp is not configured correctly.
        throw(new Exception("SSO authentication failed: ". $e->getMessage()));
        return;
    }

    if (!$valid_saml_session) {
        // Not valid session. Redirect a user to Identity Provider
        try {
            $as = new SimpleSAML_Auth_Simple($sp);
            $as->requireAuth();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // SimpleSAMLphp is not configured correctly.
            throw(new Exception("SSO authentication failed: ". $e->getMessage()));
            return;
        }
    }

    // At this point, the user is authenticated by the Identity Provider, and has access
    // to the attributes received with SAML assertion.
    $attributes = $as->getAttributes();
```

it does forward me all the way to the identity server and asks for credentials. but upon returning to the service provider i get the error

```
State information lost   
SimpleSAML_Error_NoState: NOSTATE
```

i found this wiki page https://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp/wiki/LostState, but nothing i did after reading it (like changing the `'session.cookie.domain'` in `config\config.php`, which just sent the pages into an infinite refresh loop) worked

does anyone have any ideas? did i set it up incorrectly? i'm thinking maybe the web application itself has to be the service provider? i.e. `test.domain.com/webapplication/simplesaml/` so that the two are on the same domain?

Answer (score 2):

You can try change the session store.type in config.php. You can do it in the service provider or identity provider. Some way that the two have different session storages. Works for me.